# after 'composer install' no dependency folders are added

Tags: php, composer-php, vagrant

The 'vendor' folder and 'composer' subfolders are created but there are no folders for the actual code.

My composer.json is:

```
{
    "name": "vagrant/backend_build",
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "1.0.*"
    }
}
```

After installing, the directory tree looks as follows:

```
.
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    └── composer
        ├── autoload_classmap.php
        ├── autoload_namespaces.php
        ├── autoload_psr4.php
        ├── autoload_real.php
        ├── autoload_static.php
        ├── ClassLoader.php
        ├── installed.json
        └── LICENSE
```

I have run `composer diagnose` and all checks come back OK. Has anyone run into this before?

**Update:**

If I run install with the `--prefer-source` option, the folders are created, so maybe the issue is with the extraction of files? I have `unzip` and `php-zip` installed.

I'm running Centos 8 in a Virtualbox VM.

Output of `composer diagnose`:

```
Checking composer.json: WARNING
No license specified, it is recommended to do so. For closed-source software you may use "proprietary" as license.
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: OK
Composer version: 1.10.10
PHP version: 7.2.24
PHP binary path: /usr/bin/php
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1c FIPS  28 May 2019
```

Output of `composer install -vvv`:

```
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Checked CA file /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem: valid
Executing command (/home/appuser/backend_build): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/home/appuser/backend_build): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git --version
Executing command (/home/appuser/backend_build): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD --no-show-signature
Executing command (/home/appuser/backend_build): hg branch
Executing command (/home/appuser/backend_build): fossil branch list
Executing command (/home/appuser/backend_build): fossil tag list
Executing command (/home/appuser/backend_build): svn info --xml
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /home/vagrant/.config/composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Running 1.10.10 (2020-08-03 11:35:19) with PHP 7.2.24 on Linux / 4.18.0-193.14.2.el8_2.x86_64
Loading composer repositories with package information
Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
Writing /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Reading /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2015%2486cba306ff75ef375dcc46fbff9031939d8c056f7386d0d91e785158866a7293.json
Writing /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2015.json into cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2016.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2017.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2018.json from cache
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2019%244abfb99568f1cf60a2e904b779ec611428598f1cd299ba62438fdc327dbc12ed.json
Writing /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2019.json into cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2019-10.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2020-01.json from cache
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2020-04%240070b25f697f1cd140c6bd3c52368cc49f59e51e24ca9b95db5fd471a3a82bc4.json
Writing /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2020-04.json into cache
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2020-07%2470086e873f5943854eb39e8fa3ba8ce959e613ee35e79f6230cc89e448af9521.json
Writing /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-2020-07.json into cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json from cache
Downloading http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-latest%2414e66ed837cc6d9209e2638687b1c756524ff87fb65efa6a53d95a6e20d80c2f.json
Writing /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json into cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-monolog$monolog.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-psr$log.json from cache
Resolving dependencies through SAT
Looking at all rules.
Something's changed, looking at all rules again (pass #1)
Dependency resolution completed in 0.001 seconds
Analyzed 129 packages to resolve dependencies
Analyzed 87 rules to resolve dependencies
Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
Installs: psr/log:1.1.3, monolog/monolog:2.1.1
  - Installing psr/log (1.1.3): Reading /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/files/psr/log/eba32e017e823df412a2fcdb3e04b6766157b3ad.zip from cache
Loading from cache
 Extracting archiveExecuting command (CWD): unzip -qq  '/home/appuser/backend_build/vendor/psr/log/703bc8818ea8ff460d7a482eae7988de' -d '/home/appuser/backend_build/vendor/composer/96bb17a3'
    REASON: monolog/monolog 2.1.1 requires psr/log ^1.0.1 -> satisfiable by psr/log[1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3].

  - Installing monolog/monolog (2.1.1): Reading /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/files/monolog/monolog/7e4ccae8ff83404ac2ec2717a3174b8e28ef1135.zip from cache
Loading from cache
 Extracting archiveExecuting command (CWD): unzip -qq  '/home/appuser/backend_build/vendor/monolog/monolog/aac7ed3c6a24b3c9b06adcd6102cd372' -d '/home/appuser/backend_build/vendor/composer/2c5601d8'
    REASON: Required by the root package: Install command rule (install monolog/monolog 2.1.0|install monolog/monolog 2.1.1)

monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing elasticsearch/elasticsearch (Allow sending log messages to an Elasticsearch server via official client)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-amqplib/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server (via driver))
monolog/monolog suggests installing mongodb/mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server (via library))
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
Reading /home/appuser/backend_build/vendor/composer/installed.json
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
1 package you are using is looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
```

Comment: Did you tried to run `composer update`? You may have old `composer.lock` without any dependency installed.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? Does `composer install -v`provide any more information?

Comment: `composer update` didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: In terms of debugging, I tried everything I can think of before posting this. 

`composer install -v` doesn't show any error, other than a PHP warning about missing shared object files, and a warning about being unable to open /tmp/session.
I am running composer as a non-privileged user but the file system is owned by the user in question and so they should have permission to write to it.